# Слова «пользователь» и «соглашение» с прописной?

Tags: орфография

Пример текста.

> Акцепт – полное принятие Пользователем условий Соглашения.

Нужно ли писать эти слова с заглавной буквы?

Comment: А чего их расставлять-то? Они в начале слова вообще-то.

Comment: @behemothus Не знаю, но много где видел, что данные слова пишутся с заглавной буквы, например https://new.shop.esetnod32.ru/catalog/payment_and_delivery/contracts/technical_support_buss.php

Comment: Ну и пишите в начале слова. **Расставлять**-то куда?

Comment: @behemothus подправил вопрос

Comment: См. ссылку в ответе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это соглашение, предлагаемое целому *кругу лиц* (типа лицензионного), то "пользователь" (= любой перешедший по ссылке в знак согласия) может упоминаться только с маленькой буквы, поскольку нет возможности условно обозначить конкретное лицо, сославшись на имя. Если же соглашение составлено для *конкретного* пользователя, на которого несколько раз ссылаются в тексте, то для употребления с заглавной слова "Пользователь" его нужно предварительно ввести со ссылкой на имя этого человека (*Петров И. И., **далее - "Пользователь"**, обязуется...*). При необходимости многократно ссылаться в тексте на само соглашение (независимо от его типа и назначения) можно в начале текста ввести подобное обозначение: "*такое-то или настоящее соглашение (**далее - "Соглашение***")...".